# Passing Parameter do not gett same value

Tags: android, methods, calendar

I am accessing editText value and converting it in date object. That is working fine

```
Calender c = Calender.getInstance();
EditText dob = findViewById(R.id.dob);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String time = dob.getText().toString();
 try {
      Date babyDate = sdf.parse(time);
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: "+babyDate);
      c.setTime(babyDate);
      Log.d(TAG,c.getTime().toString);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } 
callAlarm(c);
```

The issue is when I am trying to pass the date to the method as parameter so I can set alarm on it the date is not passing accurate.

```
public void callAlarm(Calender cal){
  Log.d("TAAAAAAG", cal.getTime.toString());
}
```

This is the Logcat

> 10-22 14:14:53.762 2962-2962/com.hamzaawais.motherscare D/TAAAAAAAAAAG: onClick: Tue Oct 02 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2018
>
> 10-22 14:14:55.598 2962-2962/com.hamzaawais.motherscare D/TAAAAAAAAAAG: Thu Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2020

Comment: There's an Exception being thrown on `c.setTime()`. Check the stacktrace it prints.

Comment: I am new to android can you please tell me how I can stacktrace it  ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Comment: Thanks alot got my issue